# How to convert Getjson to values in a dictionary or array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a Javascript function and get the below values in console if I run the codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/json.php',function(urldata){
         console.log(urldata);
    });
})
```

I get the below in console:

```
{data: Array(3), draw: 1, recordsTotal: 3, recordsFiltered: 30}
data: Array(3)
0: (6) [1, 'Tokyo', 'Japan', '83', '9', 0]
1: (6) [2, 'Paris', 'France', '16', '8', 0]
2: (6) [3, 'Rome', 'Italy', '44', '6', 0]
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I tried to put them in an array but I got undefined error message.

```
var arr = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://example.com/json.php',function(urldata){
             for(k in urldata)
            {
               alert("City: " + k[1] + " Country: " + k[2]);
               arr.push(k[1], k[2])
            }
        });
    })
```

I would like to have the below output in an array or dictionary with easy access to the values:

```
+---+-------+--------+
| 1 | Tokyo | Japan  |
+---+-------+--------+
| 2 | Paris | France |
+---+-------+--------+
| 3 | Rome  | Italy  |
+---+-------+--------+
```

Please, what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the structure of the response, try replacing your callback to `arr.push(urldata.data)`

```
let arr = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://example.com/json.php',function(urldata){
            arr.push(urldata.data)
            // console.log(urldata)
        });
    })
```

**Updated**

Based on the provided response on your `console.log`,

```
data: Array(3)
0: (6) [1, 'Tokyo', 'Japan', '83', '9', 0]
1: (6) [2, 'Paris', 'France', '16', '8', 0]
2: (6) [3, 'Rome', 'Italy', '44', '6', 0]
```

You can extract the data by using the following adjustments.
Take note that I just used `for loop` for simplicity and for you to be able to see it, but there are cleaner methods for this.

```
let arr = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('http://example.com/json.php',function(urldata) {
    for (let i=0; i<urldata.data.length; i++) {
      let formattedData = `City: ${urldata.data[i][1]} Country: ${urldata.data[i][2]}`
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you, your code stores the data. I tried to get the table above but it gives undefined message. I tried this: alert("City: " + arrk[1] + " Country: " + arr[2]);. A for loop would get the result like the table but I could not figure it how get data back from the array.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the actual error that says "undefined message"?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine! :) I see the for loop and how it works. Could you please tell me what other cleaner method is there?

Comment: Nice :) As to other cleaner methods for filtering data in array, you can check `map`, `for ... of` and some others. :)